# Simple MIDI/trigger pedals

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, midi-controller-drums

I have an Arturia KeyStep and Roland SPD-SX, which I use with Ableton live. What I would like to do, is to connect two pedals of some sort that could be used as additional MIDI inputs.

1. Are there any big isolated single button MIDI foot controllers? I only find models with many buttons (four and more), but I will not use them.
2. Is it possible to make a chain of two of them and connect via a USB midi controller like KeyStep or SPD-SX (they both have MIDI input)?
3. Can I just use sustain pedals as triggers like Roland DP-2 with a sample pad?

I'm open to any general suggestion `=)` I just want two big buttons close to my hills that I can use with Ableton live to control loopers and change instruments.

Comment: Could you use a stenographer foot pedal?  I have one that connects via USB which I use with "Transcribe!" to control playback.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your first question, but as for 2 and 3, yes. As long as each device supports MIDI in and MIDI out, they should be able to chain together appropriately. Double check with each device though, as some devices will process MIDI in instead of forwarding it.

But Ableton is really, REALLY good with MIDI. So as long as your daisy-chained monstrosity is sending two *different* MIDI signals, they can be mapped to two different functions.

This is where my first point is important, because if your MIDI in pedal is processing the signal, it may send either pedal press as the same MIDI channel. In that case, both pedals would trigger the same action. So ensure whatever pedal you're using the chain to the other via MIDI in is able to forward the MIDI in signal as a separate channel and you should be good to go.